# How to Access Subsite of HostWeb using Sharepoint Hosted Apps

Tags: sharepoint-2013

How to Access Subsite of HostWeb using Sharepoint Hosted Apps?
I want to access a list in a subsite of the Hostweb in which the app is hosted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I will try to answer it.

The term "Host Web" is really relative, and in this case it means the site that the app is installed on.

To go outside of this, you need two things.

1. You need the permission in the application. In the App Manifest, there is a tab for permissions. There are two that you may be interested in: "Web" and "Site Collection". Here is a link that describes these: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142383.aspx
2. The next thing would be getting outside of the scope of the AppWeb. This is done with something called a RequestExecutor. This allows you to ask SharePoint to make a call on your behalf to go outside of the scope of the App, but it will only go where you give it permission to. Here is a link to that process: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179927.aspx

Doing both of these things will give you access to get whatever you need to get.

Answer (score 0):

```
function RetrieveWebsFromHostWeb() {

var websUrl = _appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/site/rootWeb/webinfos?@target='" + _hostWebUrl + "'";

$.ajax({
    url: websUrl,
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: this.OnRetrieveWebsFromHostWebSucceeded
});
```

}

```
function OnRetrieveWebsFromHostWebSucceeded(sender, args) {

console.log(sender.d.results);
```

}

```
function GetQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}
var _appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(this.GetQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
var _hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(this.GetQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
```